# Memory leak. How to use delete properly? BN_bn2hex _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)

Tags: c++, openssl

I am new to C++.  I can't declare result_str as *result_str. What am I doing wrong? How to avoid memory leak? BN_bn2hex function is: char *BN_bn2hex(const BIGNUM *a);

```
    point_compressed_dec = EC_POINT_point2bn(group, pub_key, POINT_CONVERSION_COMPRESSED, NULL, ctx); //public DEC format

    char *result_str = new char;
    result_str = BN_bn2hex(point_compressed_dec); 

    out << result_str << endl;

    char *result_str2 = new char; // Works fine
    *result_str2 = 5;             //

    delete result_str;  // Doesn't work
    delete result_str2; // Works fine
```

Comment: `result_str = BN_bn2hex(point_compressed_dec);` "throws away" the object you `new`ed and makes the pointer point to a different object

Comment: From the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_bn2hex.html) you need to free the returned string by calling `OPENSSL_free()` - "The string must be freed later using OPENSSL_free()."  This is why calling `delete result_str` isn't working. You don't need to allocate the string before calling the openssl function, it will allocate it and return it.  You have to later free it using their free function [OPENSSL_free()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/OPENSSL_malloc.html)

Comment: It was good that people could help you, but there are guidelines about providing complete examples of your problem.   The guidelines aren’t just pedantry.  Distilling of your problem into a small enough example that people can try often illustrates the problem.   Helping yourself is a much greater experience than having somebody help you.

Comment: Since you are new to C++, I feel I need to point out OepnSSL is written in C, and there are other problems mixing C and C++, so be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem: Leak

```
char *result_str = new char;
```

Allocates a single character points `result_str`  at it.

```
result_str = BN_bn2hex(point_compressed_dec);
```

reassigns `result_str` to point at something returned by `BN_bn2hex` that may or may not be `delete`-able. The single character assigned on the line above is leaked because nothing points at it anymore.

## Solution: Leak

Do not allocate that character. You don't need it. Instead assign the result of `BN_bn2hex` directly to `result_str`.

```
char *result_str = BN_bn2hex(point_compressed_dec);
```

## Problem: delete

After

```
result_str = BN_bn2hex(point_compressed_dec);
```

`result_str` points at a string returned by `BN_bn2hex`. Since you don't know how the memory was allocated (you can only safely `delete` that which was `new`ed) you cannot safely release it yourself. [The documentation for `BN_bn2hex`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_bn2hex.html) instructs you to free this memory with `OPENSSL_free`.

## Solution: delete

Do not `delete`. Instead follow the instructions in the documentation and use `OPENSSL_free`.

## Sidenote

Check that `result_str` is not `NULL` before attempting to use it. If the result is `NULL`, use `ERR_get_error` to find out why.

Comment: Very clear and detailed answer dealing with each part of the issue.

Comment: @ИльяЯковлев - Please learn from this, reading the documentation should ALWAYS come before asking someone else.  ALWAYS. I can't stress that enough. You will be amazed what you will learn just by reading the documentation and paying attention to examples, requirements, etc. I am not trying to sound mean in what I am saying. I am just trying to stress the importance of documentation. It is there to help you.